# Checked no funciona!

Tags: css3, ccs

Estoy perdiendo mi cabeza por aqui, estoy intentando hacer un menú responsive sencillo donde al seleccionar el menu aparezca desde la izquierda, aun no le he añadido el transition pero no se por que el checked no funciona! estoy usando el selector ~ ya que ambos son hijos del mismo padre, pero no funciona, llevo una hora en esto, no sé que mas hacer. La estructura me parece que esta correcta, he intentado cambiar la posición de los elementos pero nada funciona, cualquier ayuda o colaboración se lo agradecería

```
<body>
    <header class="cabecera_menu">
        <input type="checkbox" id="btn-menu">
        <label for="btn-menu"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
 
        <nav class="contenedor_menu">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li class="menu__op"><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li class="menu__op"><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
                <li class="menu__op"><a href="#">Promociones</a></li>
                <li class="menu__op"><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                <li class="menu__op"><a href="#">Conocenos mas</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>  
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/* Ejercicios practicos */
*, *::before, *::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
}

body{
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.cabecera_menu label, #btn-menu {
    display:none;
    
}

.menu {
    background: rgb(99, 99, 165);
    display:flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.menu__op a {
    color:white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display:block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.menu__op:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

@media only screen and (max-width:860px){

    .fa-bars {
       padding-top: 3px;
        font-size:30px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        cursor:pointer;
        color:white;
    }

    header {
        background: rgb(99, 99, 165);
    }
 
    .cabecera_menu label {
        display:block;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border-right: 1px solid white;
    }

    header label:hover {
        background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    .menu {
        margin-top: 0px;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-right:50%;
    
    }

    .contenedor_menu{
        margin-left: -50%;
    }
    ul li a {
        border-top: 1px solid white;
    }

  
    #btn-menu:checked ~ .contenedor_menu {

        margin-left:0;
    }
```

Comment: Hola @edmblue, lo probé y pone y quita el menú. Prueba presionar las telcas **`Ctrl + Shift + R`** para que descarte que no sea el caché del navegador.

Comment: Que error tan tonto, muchas gracias